# Error when installing Ruby on Linux

Tags: ruby, linux, installation

I ran this command in the terminal on a Fresh Linux install.

> sudo aptget install ruby1.9 libruby1.9
>   libreadlineruby1.9 irb1.9

I'm getting this error:

Unable to locate package irbl.9

This command was taken directly from the Pickaxe book. Any suggestions on why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

If you copied and pasted the error then the problem is that you have an L instead of a 1 in irb1.9

Answer (score 0):

At your command-line, type:

```
apt-cache search irb
```

and look for a line starting with `irb1.9`. I just checked mine and can't find that, so it might be that irb1.9 isn't available in your distribution. And, it might be that it is already included in your ruby1.9.

That said, you might want to look into [installing Ruby using RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install). It creates a sandbox for multiple Rubies, allowing you to easily switch back and forth or test code against all your installed versions. If you go that route be sure to read the page and complete the "post install" section. Also, do `rvm notes` after installing and make sure you have all the dependencies, then read the info about [using gems](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rubies/rubygems/), specifically the part that says "DO NOT use sudo...".

Comment: Regarding RVM, are you saying I run that terminal command he mentions on the site and I can now run Ruby scripts with no additional configuration needed?

Comment: I am saying that RVM will do a lot of the configuration for you. How much depends on the state of your machine, and if you have the prerequisites installed and if you can follow the directions he's provided. I think it's an easy install for most systems.